# JES- Selection Sort using Nested For Loops

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, nested, jes

I need to write a program that generates a list containing an arbitrary number of random integers and produces a sorted list using the "selection sort" algorithm.

I don't know how to use i to count from 0 to the last index of the list.

I also am unsure of how to use j to count from i + 1 to the last index of the list.

When I run the program, it simply generates a random list of 10 integers, some negative and some positive. Below is a pic of the instructions, and my code so far. Thanks for any kind of help.

```
def main():    

  list= []    

  length= 10

  num_operations= 0


  while num_operations < length :  

    list= list + [randint(1, 100)] 

    num_operations+=1    

  print list


  for i in range( 0, length ) :    
    i = i + 1    
    min = i    
    for j in range ( i + 1, length ) :   
      if list[j] < list[min] :    
        min = j

  if min != i :
    temp= list[i]
    list[i]= list[min]
    list[min]= temp
```

Comment: Sorry about the link! Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/br8aZ.png

Answer (score 0):

First something is wrong with your min calculation, the problem is the definition of min isn't as its right place, try this:

```
  min = 0
  for i in range( 0, length) :
    for j in range ( i + 1, length) :
      if list[j] < list[min] :
        min = j
    i = i + 1
```